# How to access shared subfolder in Outlook with VBA

Tags: vba, outlook

I have some VBA which sometimes fails on the line `Set Folder = Inbox.Folders("xxx")` with the below error message.

`Folder = Inbox.Folders` is returning 0 folders even though I can see them in the the Outlook pane.

> Run-time error '-2147221233 (8004010f)'
> The attempted operation failed. An object could not be found.

```vb
Sub Export()

Select_Date.Show

'Dim OutlookApp As Outlook.Application
'Dim OutlookNamespace As NameSpace
'Dim Folder As MAPIFolder
'Dim OutlookMail As Variant
'Dim i As Integer
'Dim olNS As Outlook.NameSpace
'Dim Start_Date As Date
'Dim saveFolder As String

Start_Date = DateValue(Select_Date.ComboBox1.Value & " " & Select_Date.ComboBox2.Value & " " & Select_Date.ComboBox3.Value)
overwrite_flag = Select_Date.CheckBox1.Value

saveFolder = "K:\xxxx "

Set OutlookApp = New Outlook.Application
Set OutlookNamespace = OutlookApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")

Set objowner = OutlookNamespace.CreateRecipient("xx.xxx@xxx.com")
objowner.Resolve
    
Set Inbox = OutlookNamespace.GetSharedDefaultFolder(objowner, olFolderInbox)
    
'Set Folder_test = Inbox.Folders.GetLast
Set Folder = Inbox.Folders("xxx")
'Set Folder = Session.Folders("xxx").Folders("Inbox")
    
i = 1
For Each OutlookMail In Folder.Items
    If TypeOf OutlookMail Is MailItem Then
        If OutlookMail.ReceivedTime >= Start_Date And OutlookMail.Subject = "xxxx" Then
            For Each attach In OutlookMail.Attachments
                savename = saveFolder & Format(DateAdd("d", 35, OutlookMail.ReceivedTime), "yyyymmdd") & ".csv"
                If (Dir$(savename) <> "") Then
                    If overwrite_flag = True Then
                       Kill savename ' delete if file exists
                       attach.SaveAsFile savename
                    End If
                Else: attach.SaveAsFile savename
                End If
                attach.SaveAsFile savename
            Next attach
        End If
    End If
    i = i + 1
Next OutlookMail

Set Folder = Nothing
Set OutlookNamespace = Nothing
Set OutlookApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: There are many posts where the answer is to uncheck “Download shared folders”. Apparently the code will be very slow.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to iterate over all subfolders and find the required one by checking its name.

Also I've noticed that your code iterates over all items in the folder which is not really a good idea! Use the [Find](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff869662.aspx)/[FindNext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff862482.aspx) or [Restrict](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff869597.aspx) methods of the `Items` class. Read more about these methods in the following articles:

- [How To: Use Find and FindNext methods to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder (C#, VB.NET)](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/20/outlook-find-findnext-retrieve-mail/)
- [How To: Use Restrict method to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/23/outlook-restrict-method-retrieve-mail/)

Comment: Thank you. I'll look into the find/findnext methods. I should have added that when I get the error I can examine Inbox.Folders and find zero sub folders even though I can see them right there in my Outlook pane.

Comment: e.g. Inbox.Folders.GetLast returns nothing

Comment: Do you see the required folder if you add it manually in Outlook? Are you sure the folder exists?

Comment: Yes I can see the folder there and can access the emails manually (picture added to question). Also sometimes the code does run but rarely.

Answer (score 0):

The error is MAPI_E_NOT_FOUND, which means either the folder with that name does not exist, or that you have no access to its subfolders.

Also note that if shared folders are set to be cached, Outlook only caches the folder itself, but not its subfolders, hence you won't be able to access any subfolders.